# Polar equation to Cartesian equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The goal is to convert
$$
r = \frac{4}{5-4\sin\theta}
$$
to a Cartesian equation.

I have gotten to
$$
25x^2 + 9y^2 - 32y = 16
$$
which I am fairly sure is an ellipse but I just have no clue as to how to put it into standard form. There is a possibility I converted the polar equation incorrectly but I did it several times and kept getting the same result.

Comment: What do you mean, referring to "standard form"? The Cartesian equation seems correct to me.

Comment: Are you thinking of the "standard form" for an ellipse whose center is at the origin? The center of this ellipse is not at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Express as

$$(5x)^2+\left(3y-\dfrac{16}3\right)^2=16+\left(-\dfrac{16}3\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{20}3\right)^2$$

$$\iff\dfrac{x^2}{\left(\dfrac{20}{15}\right)^2}+\dfrac{\left(y-\dfrac{16}9\right)^2}{\left(\dfrac{20}9\right)^2}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

What happens to $\frac{x^2}{a^2}\color{red}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ when you shift the origin to $(\alpha,\beta)$?

Note that the '$\color{red}+$' in $25x^2\color{red}+9y^2-32y=16$ tells the type of conic section.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square is your friend:

$$25x^2+9y^2-32y=16\implies25x^2+9\left(y-\frac{16}9\right)^2-\frac{256}9=16\implies$$

$$25x^2+9\left(y-\frac{16}9\right)^2=\frac{400}9\implies\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac43\right)^2}+\frac{\left(y-\frac{16}9\right)^2}{\left(\frac{20}9\right)^2}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as completing squares for quadratics, but this case seems more complicated.

$$25x^2+9y^2-32y=16\longleftrightarrow25x^2+9(y^2-\frac{32}9y+\frac{16^2}{9^2})=16+\frac{16^2}9\longleftrightarrow25x^2+9(y-\frac{16}9)^2=\frac{400}9$$
$$\longleftrightarrow\frac{x^2}{\frac{400}{25\cdot9}}+\frac{(y-\frac{16}9)^2}{\frac{400}{9^2}}=1\longleftrightarrow \frac{x^2}{(\frac{4}{3})^2}+\frac{(y-\frac{16}9)^2}{(\frac{20}{9})^2}=1$$

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Can you just explain the last two steps? I get dividing by 400/9 to get the equation equal to 1 but doing that gives denominators 9/16 and 81/400 (basically upsidedown to what everyone has written - so obviously I'm doing something odd)

Comment: When you put 9/16 and 81/400 down to the denominator, you need to flip them upside down, so they become 16/9 and 400/8. Just like when you want to divide something, you can also multiply its recipricol.